# Displaying custom post type using terms instead of taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I'm building quite a complex site at the moment, and need a way to display all custom post types using various means.

My custom post is currently laid out and defined in this structure:

**Custom post type:** Offer

**Taxonomy:**

- Brand 1

  - Offer type 1
  - Offer type 2
  - Offer type 3
- Brand 2

  - Offer type 1
  - Offer type 2
  - Offer type 3
- Brand 3

  - Offer type 1
  - Offer type 2
  - Offer type 3

At the moment, I can only display the following:

1. **A specific brand** showing *all offer types*
2. **A specific brand** show *a specific offer type*

I would also like to have it so I can display the following situation by showing a *specific offer type* showing **all brands**.

I assume that the right way to achieve this would be to create an array for the shortcode 'brand' attribute so I can list 'brand 1', 'brand 2' etc? However, I'm not sure how this would be accomplished. I cannot get the shortcode to use an array for the type either so it's all types or 1 at the moment.

The shortcode I'm using is [offers brand='brand-1' type='offer-type-1']

Hopefully the above makes sense and the current code in my theme functions.php file is as follows:

```
            function register_shortcodes() {
                add_shortcode( 'offers', 'shortcode_offer_type_by_brand' );
            }
            add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );

            /**
             * Offer Shortcode Callback
             * 
             * @param Array $atts
             *
             * @return string
             */

            //Start Offers Shortcode 1

            function shortcode_offer_type_by_brand( $atts ) {

            ob_start();

                global $wp_query,
                    $post;

                $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                    'posts' => 8, //sets number of posts
                    'pages' => false, //sets pagination
                    'brand' => '', //brand name goes here in shortcode
                    'type' => array( 'offer-type-1','offer-type-2','offer-type-3' ) //offer type is defined, by default show all offer types
                ), $atts );

                if ($atts['pages'] == true ) { //if shortcode defines pages as true, enable pagination

                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page'    => $atts['posts'],
                        'post_type'         => 'offers',
                        'tax_query'         => array( array(
                            'taxonomy'  => $atts['brand'],
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $atts['type']
                        ) )
                    ) );

                } else {
                    $loop = new WP_Query( array( //if shortcode defines pages as false or no value, disable pagination
                        'posts_per_page'    => $atts['posts'],
                        'post_type'         => 'offers',
                        'order'             => 'rand',
                        'tax_query'         => array( array(
                            'taxonomy'  => $atts['brand'],
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $atts['type']
                        ) )
                    ) );
                }

                ?>

               <?php

                if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
                   ?>
                   <h3>We currently have no offers. Please check back soon.</h3>
                   <?php
                }

                ?>

                <?php

                while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                    $loop->the_post();

                    ?>
                            <div class="offer">
                                <div class="offerText">
                                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php

                    next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $loop ->max_num_pages);
                    previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' );

                } 

                wp_reset_postdata();

                ?>

                <?php

            return ob_get_clean();

            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

**EDIT**

Using Tuhin's response, the final code used was related to his array, I used a default value on the $andor variable to always be relation 'OR' unless defined in the shortcode variable.

```
            $brands = $atts['brand'];
            $offers = $atts['type'];
            $andor = $atts['andor'];
            $args = [
                'post_type' => 'offers',
                'tax_query' => [
                    'relation' => $andor,
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $brands
                    ],
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'offer',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $offers
                    ],
                ]
            ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to ask you a question, but as I do not have enough rep now, I'm going to add an answer. As from your example, it seems like, you're using same offer terms (offer 1, offer 2, offer 3) under each brand terms, it seems like you're repeating the terms under each brand.

I think the way you're trying to achieve it could be simplified by actually having two different taxonomies. so for post type 'offers' you can have one taxonomy 'brand' and another 'offer'.

so the brand can have different values like:

- brand 1
- brand 2
- brand 3

and then you can assign different values to 'offers' like:

- offer 1
- offer 2
- offer 3

Now you can search in any combination like:

```
$brands = $atts['brand'];
$offers = $atts['type'];
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'offers',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $brands
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'offer',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $offers
        ],
    ]
];
```

This will return you all the offers post type that has any of these taxonomy entries. So if you have filled in

Comment: Just so I can get my head around this - does this mean if 'brand 1' is entered into the shortcode then it would return all the offers, and if the shortcode defined 'brand 1' AND 'offer 1' it would return only those? If 'offer 1' was defined it would return all brands and if the shortcode defined 'offer 1' AND 'brand 1' it would return only those?

Comment: we've used relation 'OR' in here. As a result, it will find all the offer post types that belongs to either 'brand1' or 'offer 1'. Howerver, if you want to restrict it to 'offers' post type that has both 'brand 1' and 'offer 1', then change that relation to 'AND'.

Comment: I've taken a further look and it's not quite right - basically I need the functionality as you describe above using 'OR', as well as 'AND' running in the same array - is this a posibility. From what I see the above (OR) works to show all brand 1 or all offer 1. Changing to (AND) displays brand 1 with offer 1.

Comment: Finally got it - using your code above fixed half my problem. However, I added in an addition to the shortcode which the user can define to include both options or just one or the other. This little addition meant that 'OR' or 'AND' could be defined, thus changing the output.

Comment: Thanks Paul, sorry as I didn't get time earlier to come back to you. Yes, you're right, you need to update the relation based on whether you've received two values or only one. Glad that it helped to solve your issue (although partially). I'll try to update the answer above with more details next time. Cheers!